# how to remove all escaped characters (that are not special characters)

Tags: c#

I am parsing some WMI query results, and some values that are empty in Powershell's `Get-CimInstance` get the value of `"\0"` from C#'s `ManagementObjectSearcher`.

I'm trying to filter them out and replace with null/empty string, but I encountered something I don't fully understand:

```
s = "\0"; // assigned by ManagementObjectSearcher, value displayed by VS 2019 debugger
var t1 = s == "\0";  // true
var t2 = s == @"\0"; // false
var t3 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s); // false
```

The value `s` is displayed as `"\0"` in debugger, but when I click on it it shows nothing (empty string).
From what I understand, `\` is used to escape special characters, but I didn't find any information about `"\0"`.

What is the best approach to get rid of all "empty but not empty" values like this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically U+0000 - the "null" character. (See the [documentation of C# escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences) for a complete list.) You can just use `string.Replace` as normal:

```cs
string filtered = original.Replace("\0", "");
```